# How to add windows stack to pivotal cloud foundry account

Tags: cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

The cf stack command in pivotal cf does not list windows stack .
The link https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-6/concepts/stacks.html lists two stacks but when I execute the same command , I see only

> cflinuxfs2   Cloud Foundry Linux-based filesystem

How can I add windows stack to my pivotal cf account?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Windows diego cell running in your Cloud Foundry environment. You should take a read through this [documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/opsguide/deploying-diego.html), that documents the install process.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/opsguide/deploying-diego.html

Comment: Hi @dan , Thanks for response. I am currently using Pivotal web services account at [pivotal Web Services](http://run.pivotal.io/) . Is there a way to add windows stack in Pivotal web services? or Do we need access to a pivotal CF setup of our own ?

Comment: At present you do need to run your own Cloud Foundry instance to be able to add a Windows cell.

Comment: Got it .We decided to setup own CF. Thanks a lot